# how to get github pull request all reviewers using python (pyGithub)

Tags: python, github, pygithub

I'm using pyGithub to interact with github, i'd like to get all reviewer list for a pull request.
There's a api `pullrequest.get_review_requests()` which only returns people who were asked for review, not returning people who joined as reviewer.
Is there any api call i can get full list of reviewer (including people who was asked for review and people who self joined as reviewer)?
Thanks.
-Neo

Answer (score 2):

"Reviews" and "review requests" are two different things that you have to combine on your own, as far as I know. One difference though is that "review requests" can be an *entire team* or a single user. "Reviews" are only associated with a single user.

With PyGitHub I think you'd be looking to do something like this:

```py
usernames_involved = set()

for review in pr.get_reviews():
    usernames_involved.add(review.user.username)

users_requested, teams_requested = pr.get_review_requests()

for user in users_requested:
    usernames_involved.add(user.username)

for team in teams_requested:
    for user in team.get_members():
        usernames_involved.add(user.username)

print(usernames_involved)
```